# Time Format String

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date, datetime-format

I am trying to decode the date-time receiving from my APIs in my required format "yyyy-MM-dd"

I receive time in 2 format

```
1. "2022-05-05T11:32:12.542Z"
2. "2022-05-06T07:33:46.59928+00:00"
```

I am able to decode first format by parsing it using following pattern

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

but not able to understand the format for the 2nd condition.

Some more example example of 2nd Condition

```
"2022-05-06T06:30:25.583988+00:00"
"2022-05-05T11:32:49.393283+00:00"
```

P.S. I don't required parsing logic only needed the pattern

Full method used in the code for parsing 1st Condition

```
fun convertToFormat(src: String): String {
    
    val originalFormat =
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
    val targetFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val date = originalFormat.parse(src)
    return targetFormat.format(date)
}
```

Comment: `Z` is actually `+00:00`, how are you parsing it and what are you exactly trying to do? Which library are you using for parsing and formatting?

Comment: @deHaar update the Question with full method. I am using KOTLIN language

Comment: ohh, the old `SimpleDateFormat`, better use the classes from `java.time` package\ - for `SimpleDateFormat`, use `X` to parse time zones as `Z` or `+01:00` (e.g. `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"`)

Comment: @user16320675 okay but could you help with pattern used in 2nd Condition

Comment: @user16320675 tried but no Success as you can observe in the example the millisecond part is sometime 5 digit long and sometime 6 digit.
 I Guess Millisecond (SSS) it maxed by 3 digit

Comment: Why do you need to parse at all if you are just returning a string? Wouldn it not be enough to do `return src.split("T")[0]` ?

Comment: kind of funny, `OffsetDateTime.parse()` can *do*  all these formats

Comment: @Eritrean as i am receiving time in UTC. I need to convert time as per user timezone basis on his location. that part i had skipped here because that is off the topic

Comment: As @user16320675 said, consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

If you only want to just pull the date portion of the input string, [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)).

```
"2022-05-05T11:32:12.542Z"
.split( "T" ) 
[ 0 ]
```

If you want to parse the input string, use `OffsetDateTime` & `LocalDate`.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse(
    input 
) 
.toLocalDate()
.toString() ;
```

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310. Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`.

## ISO 8601

Both of your exemple strings represent a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Both of your example strings are in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes support ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `Instant`

Parse your input as objects of class `Instant`.

```
Instant instant1 = Instant.parse( "2022-05-05T11:32:12.542Z" ) ;
Instant instant2 = Instant.parse( "2022-05-06T07:33:46.59928+00:00" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6cvicf).

## `LocalDate`

You want date only. So convert to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime`, and extract `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = Instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate() ;
```

Then call `LocalDate#toString` to generate text in ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD.

## Android

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later.

Android 26+ carries an implementation of *java.time*. For earlier Android, the latest tooling provides most of the functionality via “API desugaring”.

Comment: i know its terrible but I am using Kotlin wrt Android Development and for using Instant.parse  minimum API level 26 is required but i need to focus from API 23

Comment: @KartikAgarwal Incorrect. I’ll add Android info.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking the SimpleDateFormat Docs, and found this reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#examples

The pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00`, looks like very similar with this you are receiving (except about the seconds precision).

Comment: your pattern giving no Success. Seconds precision making the job tough